# Codeigniter Route Like a Asp.net Mvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am newbei at codeigniter. I developed many project of asp.net mvc and i am used to asp.net mvc routing like

domain.com/
-> HomeController - IndexAction

domain.com/Product
-> ProductController - IndexAction

domain.com/Customer/Create
-> CustomerController - CreateAction

I want to be routing at codeigniter like asp.net mvc. I don't want to write codeigniter route config again and again.

```
$route['customer'] = 'customer/index';
$route['customer/create'] = 'customer/create';
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Simple answer, yes you can. I suggest you read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you’ll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions.

**Examples**

$route['blog/joe'] = 'blogs/users/34';

$route['product/(:num)'] = 'catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1';